# Are Trigonometric Functions Dense in $C^k(S^1)?$

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

Consider the functions $\{e^{2\pi i nx}\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ defined on the interval $[0,1].$  These are all smooth periodic functions (so functions on $S^1)$ and by the Stone-Weierstrass theorem they are dense in $C^0(S^1)$ when it is given the max norm. Consider the norm on $C^k(S^1)$ given by 
$$|f|^{C^k}=\sum_{i=0}^k \text{max}_{x \in S^1}|f^{(k)}(x)|.$$

$C^k(S^1)$ is complete in this norm, but is the collection $\{e^{2\pi i nx}\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ a dense subset?

Comment: Do you mean the linear subspace spanned by $\{e^{2\pi i x}\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is dense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Landscape noted, the question should be about the linear span of $\{e^{2\pi i n x}\}$. The answer is yes, it is dense. Given $f\in C^k(S^1)$, approximate its derivative $f^{(k)}$ to within $\epsilon$ by some trigonometric polynomial $p_k(x)=\sum_n c_n e^{2\pi i n x}$. Then consider the antiderivative $p_{k-1}(x) =b+ \sum_{n\ne 0} \frac{c_n}{2\pi i n} e^{2\pi i n x}$  where $b$ is chosen so that $p_{k-1}(0)=f^{(k-1)}(0)$. By the fundamental theorem of calculus, the difference $|p_{k-1}-f^{(k-1)}|$ does not exceed $\int_0^1 \epsilon \,dx=\epsilon$. Therefore, $p_{k-1}$ is within $\epsilon$ of $f^{(k-1)}$. Repeat the process until you reach $p_0$, an $\epsilon$-approximation for $f$. Since $(p_0)^{(j)}=p_j$  for $j=1,\dots,k$, it follows that $\|p_0-f\|_{ C^k}\le (k+1)\epsilon$.