# Trigonometric polynomials are dense

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Is the set of all trigonometric polynomials in the space of continuous functions on [$-\pi,\pi]$ which are $2\pi$-periodic dense?(with sup-norm topology)Please give hints on how to find  a sequence of trigonometric functions converging to a  given continuous function.Thanks in advance

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381321/are-trigonometric-functions-dense-in-cks1